# Getting StopIteration exceptions while iterator isn't fully exhausted

Tags: python, exception, iterator, schedule

I'm just curious about strange behavior since it seems working well yet. Generally, I have the simple job:

```
 def weather_history_obtain_job(rows=itertuples):
        
    for key in mails.api_keys:
        for _ in range(490):
            try:
                row = next(rows)
            except StopIteration:
                print('The end of active tradepoint dates is reached!')
                return

            weather_frame = get_tp_weather_history(row,key)
            weather_frame[_columns].to_csv('weather_history.csv', mode='a', header=None)
```

Scheduled by the same name python library:

```
itertuples = dates_frame.itertuples()
schedule.every().day.at("07:30").do(weather_history_obtain_job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    tm.sleep(15)
```

So what I've got is several exception block prints, one per day of execution:

```
The end of active tradepoint dates is reached!
The end of active tradepoint dates is reached!
```

And my question is how come execution to the exception block, while, obviously, the iterator has not achieved the end, and execution continues just like I was expected it to take more than two days to complete the task?

Comment: You need to pass a fresh `itertuples` each time, because after the first run it will be exhausted.

Comment: @snakecharmerb it was specially designed to pass through one  ```itertuples```  with several runs of job